# Universal App AdControl error:NoAdAvailable

Tags: banner, universal

I have a Universal App with an AdControl to show a banner connected to Microsoft banner; when I work with the test appId and test appUnitId it all works fine, but if I change the appId and appUnitId with the official ones, the response is always "NoAdAvailable"; I also set all type of advertise in app dashboard in PubCenter.
The app is published in Beta.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly ,I suggest you check your official appId and appUnitId because something are ok when you work with test appId and test appUnitId.

If official appId and appUnitId are ok, you can refer to [this document](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/monetize/xaml-and-c-troubleshooting-guide) and maybe you can fix some errors.

Especially some of the markets is still on going, check if your contry is listed [on this page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/monetize/supported-markets-for-microsoft-advertising)